How to calulate a power of real-valued signal in watts?
I was Googling to find the answer to my question but did not succeed.
Given a discrete real-valued signal with $N$ samples and $F_{s}$ as the sampling frequency. Asked to calculate the power of the signal in $\textrm{dB}_{\textrm{m}}$.
To do so, as I understand, we first have to obtain power of the signal in Watts and then use the following formula:
$$
P_{\textrm{dB}_{\textrm{m}}} = 10 \log_{10} \left( \frac{P \textrm{ W}}{1 \textrm{ mW}} \right) + 30. \tag{1}
$$
Even though I am not sure about $+30$ and where it comes from, you can also answer this if you know.
The problem is I do not know how to get $P$ in Watts. The power of a discrete signal with $N$ samples, as I know, is defined as:
$$
P = \frac{1}{N}  \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \left( x \left[ n \right] \right)^{2}. \tag{2}
$$
Is this a correct formula? Is this a power in watts exactly? If I am completely wrong, could you please let me know how to do this?

Welcome to our SE. I'm afraid your question is too broad and needs a lot more context for a meaningful answer. For starters you can try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm ?

There's an error in your power to dBm formula -- the "+30" is unnecessary, unless you're taking $10 \log \frac P {1\mathrm W}$ and not $10 \log \frac P {1\mathrm mW}$.  Moreover, the power being transmitted by a physical system is composed of two quantities that multiply together to Watts, such as volts and amps, or Newtons and meters per second.  To calculate actual power you either need to know both quantities or you need to know one, and the impedance that the one thing is working into (i.e., radio usually works into 50 ohm loads).

Please edit your question with more detail: what are you actually doing, what is the sampling rate, what is the scaling from your measured quantity to your digital quantity, and what is the measured quantity, then either tell us the characteristic impedance of the system or tell us that when you're asked for "dBm" you're really being asked for fake dBm (i.e., some systems calculate a voltage "dBm" as if it were working into some commonly used impedance).

I think I managed to find an answer. I am asked to use R = 50 Ohm load and the signal is expressed in Volts. So the correct formula would be: P = 10*log10(mean(x.^2)*1e3/R)
Here mean(x.^2) is mean squared voltage, which is divided by load resistance and by 1mW expressed as multiplication by 1e3=1000. Thank you for your answers!

Still I am kind of confused by that there is no exact definition of a power of a signal which is just a function of time, as I understand. There always must be some load over which this voltage is applied, otherwise we can not talk about power. But why is then in some text books power of a signal is mean squared value of the signal over time?

To convert a sample value $y[n]$ into instantaneous physical power, you need to know what the reference voltage for the D/A converter is (and exactly how that reference voltage is related to the peak-to-peak amplitude of the output voltage coming out of the D/A converter) and you need to what the load resistance connected to the output is.
Let's say, for shits and grins, that $y[n]$ is bounded by $\pm 1$.  That is for all samples $\big| y[n] \big| \le 1$.  Now let's say that you know that the D/A converter maps $y[n]=1$ to an output $v_\mathrm{out}[n] = V_\mathrm{ref}$.
So $\big| v_\mathrm{out}[n] \big| \le V_\mathrm{ref}$ and $$v_\mathrm{out}[n] = V_\mathrm{ref} \cdot y[n]$$
Now, the instantaneous power at the load is
$$ P_\mathrm{L}[n] = \frac{|v_\mathrm{out}[n]|^2}{R_\mathrm{L}} = \frac{V_\mathrm{ref}^2}{R_\mathrm{L}} \cdot \big| y[n] \big|^2 $$
If $V_\mathrm{ref}$ is measured in volts and $R_\mathrm{L}$ is in ohms, then $P_\mathrm{L}$ is in watts.
To get average power (in whatever units), then
$$\begin{align}
 P_\mathrm{av} &= \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{2N+1} \sum_{n=-N}^{+N} P_\mathrm{L}[n] \\
  &= \frac{V_\mathrm{ref}^2}{R_\mathrm{L}} \cdot \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{2N+1} \sum_{n=-N}^{+N} \big| y[n] \big|^2 \\
\end{align} $$

The correct way to find the power of the signal would be to first specify in which units the signal is expressed. In my case it was Volts.
Power is a quantity that depends on both voltage and resistance of a load over which this voltage is applied.
The common choice of load resistance in radio communication, as was answered before in a comment by Tim Wescott, is $R = 50 \, \Omega$.
So the power of such a signal over such a resistance is $P = \frac{V^{2}}{R}$, from where I want to first get a mean power and then express it in terms of dB$_{\textrm{m}}$.
Power_mean = mean(V.^2)/R = mean(signal.^2)/R 
    
Power_dBm = 10*log10(Power_mean * 1e3) = 10*log10(mean(signal.^2)*1e3/R)
```

